# Export Permissions for multiple Shares

Tags: powershell, permissions, export, share, acl

Due to sensitive data that I am working with, I am unable to use third party tools (I know they exist but unable to use them)

I really need to create a script that exports Permissions for multiple shares (I need the parent folder only, as they contain thousands as child)
The idea is that I don't know how to put "-Recursive" so that the entire output will be exported on the same sheet and not create a new one for each of the shares.
Already excluded types of users and I got the Get-Item so there will not be any subfolders

If I try the below one, it just overwrites with the next in line, on the same sheet.
Any kind of support will be appreciated

'''

```
$Folder="\\storage1\a\b\c\d"
$Folder="\\storage2\a\b\c\d\e"
$Folder="\\storage2\a\l\m"
$AllFolders = Get-Item -Path $Folder -Force --recurse
$Results = @() 
Foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        if ($Access.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $Access.IdentityReference -notlike "domain\Domain Admins" -and $Access.IdentityReference -notlike "CREATOR OWNER" -and $access.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD Group'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
            $Results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -path "C:\Scripts\Permissionstest.csv"
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It looks like under the path you must put all the values on same line, and it makes sense. you can not state that an object has multiple values. Now, it works :)

```
**$Folder="\\storage1\a\b\c\d" , "\\storage2\a\b\c\d\e" , "\\storage2\a\l\m"
$AllFolders = Get-Item -Path $Folder -Force
$Results = @() 
Foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access) {
        if ($Access.IdentityReference -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $Access.IdentityReference -notlike "domain\Domain Admins" -and $Access.IdentityReference -notlike "CREATOR OWNER" -and $access.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD Group'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
            $Results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -path "C:\Scripts\Permissionstest.csv"**
```